# Adding event on android google calendar app by clicking an URL

Tags: android, calendar

I want to generate an event file (maybe file format is ics ?) on my website. When user uses phone to click this url, it will trigger android google calendar app and add to user's calendar automatically. I have generate an ics file directly, but it is not work (log shows "E/ICalProvider(xxx): Could not retrieve calendar from ICal file Uri!") ...
Does anyone know how to achieve this goal ? thanks a lot !